# org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (NameError) uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby, jruby, activemerchant

I'm getting the following error from a JRuby wrapping of the ActiveMerchant library:

```
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (NameError) uninitialized constant ActiveMerchant::Billing::SecurePayAuGateway
    at org.jruby.RubyModule.const_missing(org/jruby/RubyModule.java:3345)
    at org.jruby.RubyModule.const_get(org/jruby/RubyModule.java:3290)
    at RUBY.createGateway(classpath:/scripts/main.rb:79)
```

The code initiating it is:

```
gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::const_get(name).new(options)
```

I think this is happening because there is some dynamic loading of the gateways happening in gateways.rb:

```
module ActiveMerchant
    module Billing
        load_path = Pathname.new(__FILE__ + '/../../..')
        Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/gateways/**/*.rb'].each do |filename|
            gateway_name      = File.basename(filename, '.rb')
            gateway_classname = "#{gateway_name}_gateway".camelize
            gateway_filename  = Pathname.new(filename).relative_path_from(load_path).sub_ext('')

            autoload(gateway_classname, gateway_filename)
        end
    end
end
```

This works during unit tests because the Ruby files are real files in my target directory. However in the final application, the Ruby files are contained within a Jar which is in a Jar.

Anyone know why this is happening and how to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Which gateway are you trying to teach? From Active Merchant's github there is no

```
ActiveMerchant::Billing::SecurePayAuGateway
```

But there is a

```
ActiveMerchant::Billing::SecurePayGateway
```

And a

```
ActiveMerchant::Billing::SecurePayTechGateway
```

To test, instead of

```
gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::const_get(name).new(options)
```

Try

```
gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::SecurePayGateway
```

If this works, you know the problem is your gateway = method and you can fix this accordingly

Comment: SecurePayAuGateway is here: https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/blob/master/lib/active_merchant/billing/gateways/secure_pay_au.rb. I've debugged JRuby and can see that none of the gateways are being loaded as constants of the Billing module when the gem is wrapped into a jar, but they all get loaded during Unit testing because the unit tests reference real files in the Maven target directory.